# Files/DLL's required for a C++ program on another PC

Tags: c++, dll, required

So if I wanted to distribute my program to someone else's PC that I made with C++, what DLL's are absolutely required to have on that PC to be able to run the program?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well it's a bit hard to answer without knowing what your program does, and specially what library it uses.

I think this could help you:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kche8ah.aspx

Answer (score 1):

There is a tool called depends.exe which will help you to determine that:
http://www.dependencywalker.com/

> Dependency Walker is a free utility that scans any 32-bit or 64-bit Windows module (exe, dll, ocx, sys, etc.) and builds a hierarchical tree diagram of all dependent modules.

Comment: I see... I will use that to check it and using the ^ list, thanks

Comment: Yep. It's a must-have tool among Windows developers. It specifically shows you what libraries are missing.

Answer (score 0):

I recently had a similar issue and I tried several approaches, what finally helped me:

- Get all linked DLLs with the already mentioned dependency walker
- There may be DLLs loaded during runtime which may not show up in dependency walker: Use  [ListDlls](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896656.aspx) on a started process or try using [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645) to determine which DLL files (in what paths) are actually opened by your executable.